# Python lists gets overwritten when initialised

Tags: python

I am making a console simulator similar to cmd or Terminal.
To get input from the keyboard and append it in a list, this is my code:

```py
#####INITIALISE########
import bge
cont=bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own=cont.owner
own['Text']=""
alltext=[""]
######## Write text to array #########
if own.sensors['ENTER'].positive:
    alltext[len(alltext)-1]=own['keyin']
    alltext.append("")
    own['keyin']=""
else:
    alltext[len(alltext)-1]=own['keyin']
own['text']=alltext
print(alltext)
```

Here, the `alltext[]`  gets erased every time the code is run.
is there a way to prevent that?

**EDIT**:I figured it out....

Comment: idk python, its probably because alltext=[""] is executed every time? check if it exists first and skip the initialization if something is there . if (len(alltext) != 0) {... }

Comment: your first instance of "Text" is capitalized while the following is lowercase. you are appending nothing after the if statement "alltext.append("")". again i'm not well versed in python, but could you elaborate on what you are tying to accomplish? i'm having difficulties understanding based on your code? just adding input strings to a list? alltext.append( own['Text'] ) ;

Comment: Since you figured it out, you could just post a brief answer to your own question, so others can see what the problem was